# parsing a tab-separated file in Python

Tags: python, tabs, io

I'm trying to parse a tab-separated file in Python where a number placed k tabs apart from the beginning of a row, should be placed into the k-th array.

Is there a built-in function to do this, or a better way, other than reading line by line and do all the obvious processing a naive solution would perform?

Comment: sometimes easy to forget, but it's customary to accept an answer to your question..

Answer (score 72):

You can use [the `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) to parse tab seperated value files easily.

```
import csv

with open("tab-separated-values") as tsv:
    for line in csv.reader(tsv, dialect="excel-tab"): #You can also use delimiter="\t" rather than giving a dialect.
        ...
```

Where `line` is a list of the values on the current row for each iteration.

Edit: As suggested below, if you want to read by column, and not by row, then the best thing to do is use the `zip()` builtin:

```
with open("tab-separated-values") as tsv:
    for column in zip(*[line for line in csv.reader(tsv, dialect="excel-tab")]):
        ...
```

Comment: whenever an element is missing there are two consecutive tabs. will that work?

Comment: @Bob Why don't you try it and see? (But yes, it will).

Comment: @Lattyware: Your use of "file" as a variable name is a no-no... ;)

Comment: @martineau: of all the default builtin names to rebind, `file` is the least problematic, esp. because it doesn't even exist in 3.  Y'all can have "for file in files:` when you pry it from my cold, dead hands! ;^)

Comment: @martineau I'm a Python 3.x man, so I sometimes forget this is smashing `file` in 2.x. Good point, however. Edited.

Answer (score 15):

I don't think any of the current answers really do what you said you want. (Correction: I now see that @Gareth Latty / @Lattyware has incorporated my answer into his own as an "Edit" near the end.)

Anyway, here's my take:

Say these are the tab-separated values in your input file:

```
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
```

then this:

```py
with open("tab-separated-values.txt") as inp:
    print( list(zip(*(line.strip().split('\t') for line in inp))) )
```

would produce the following:

```
[('1', '6', '11', '16'), 
 ('2', '7', '12', '17'), 
 ('3', '8', '13', '18'), 
 ('4', '9', '14', '19'), 
 ('5', '10', '15', '20')]
```

As you can see, it put the k-th element of each row into the k-th array.

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
>>> s='1\t2\t3\t4\t5'
>>> [x for x in s.split('\t')]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

For a file:

```
# create test file:
>>> with open('tabs.txt','w') as o:
...    s='\n'.join(['\t'.join(map(str,range(i,i+10))) for i in [0,10,20,30]])
...    print >>o, s

#read that file:
>>> with open('tabs.txt','r') as f:
...    LoL=[x.strip().split('\t') for x in f]
... 
>>> LoL
[['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'], 
 ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19'], 
 ['20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], 
 ['30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39']]
>>> LoL[2][3]
23
```

If you want the input transposed:

```
>>> with open('tabs.txt','r') as f:
...    LoT=zip(*(line.strip().split('\t') for line in f))
... 
>>> LoT[2][3]
'32'
```

Or **(better still)** use the csv module in the default distribution...

Comment: In Python, making an empty list and then appending values is an anti-pattern. That's what list comprehensions are for.

Comment: @Lattyware: I personally do not find the first form hard to read, but you are right -- a nested list comprehension is probably more Pythonic. Edited.

Comment: @drewk: `[x.split('\t') for f.split('\n')]` makes no sense. There's no `x` and files objects don't have a `split()` method.

Comment: @martineau: perfect example of why to use the csv module, no? typo fixed. I tested it

Comment: @drewk: Well, not so much...most likely the latter thing IMHO. ;)

Comment: @martineau: Interesting that you interpreted that the OP wanted to transpose the row / col of the file being read. Unclear to me one way or the other. If that is what is wanted, use `zip()` as you did. Thanks for your patient coaching...

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it like this way by python pandas [pd.read_csv ('file_name.tsv',
sep='\t')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3GQ5.png)

---

[Note: need to install pandas with this command [pip install pandas]](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/)