# Replacing missing values and strings with 0 and values

Tags: python, r, string, replace

I have a dataframe with missing values. How can I write either a python or an R code to replace empty spaces with 0, a single string with 1, and multiple strings joined by "\t" with a number corresponding to how many "\t"s + 1.

my data frame:

```
        col1    col2    col3
row1    5blue   2green5 white
row2            white   green\twhite3\t3blue5
row3    blue3           white
row4    7blue   green2  
row5            3green  3white6
row6    6blue   green\t6white7  green   
row7    5blue5  6green  white
row8    blue6
```

Output expected:

```
        col1    col2    col3
row1    1   1   1
row2    0   1   3
row3    1   0   1
row4    1   1   0   
row5    0   1   1
row6    1   2   1   
row7    1   1   1
row8    1   0   0
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What is your delimiter? Spaces? That's what it looks like. Is that dataframe part of a text file?

Comment: Is the data frame part of a file?

Comment: Yes, read from a csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a function that goes to each column element and checks if the element is a space (You can change that depending on what you have. It looks likes a space to me) and returns 0 if it is, otherwise it splits the string by "\t" and counts the strings that are produced.

```
# example dataset
dt = data.frame(col1 = c("green\twhite3\t3blue5","green"),
                col2 = c(" ", "green\twhite3"), stringsAsFactors = F)

dt

#                   col1         col2
# 1 green\twhite3\t3blue5             
# 2               green green\twhite3


ff = function(x) 
{
  res = vector()                                                             # create an empty vector to store counts for each element
  for (i in 1:length(x)){                                                    # iterate through each element
        res[i] = ifelse(x[i]==" ", 0, length(unlist(strsplit(x[i],"\t"))))   # if the element is space return 0, else split string by \t and count new strings
                        }
  return(res)                                                                # return the stored values
}


data.frame(sapply(dt, function(x) ff(x)))                                    # apply the function to all columns and save it as a data.frame

#     col1 col2
# 1    3    0
# 2    1    2
```

Comment: your R code works perfectly for me. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Happy to help. Let me know if you find any limitations in the future and I'll update it.

Answer (score 2):

[Parsing Tab Delimited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059390/parsing-a-tab-separated-file-in-python)

Read this post above. It covers using python csv module to parse tab delimited. I think it will help you.

**Input File data_frame.txt**

```
5blue   2green5 white
    white   green\twhite3\t3blue5
blue3       white
7blue   green2  
    3green  3white6
6blue   green\t6white7  green
5blue5  6green  white
```

The code below

```
import csv

data_frame = open('data_frame.txt','r')             ## create input file for dataframe
output_matrix = []                                  ## output matrix
reader = csv.reader(data_frame, dialect="excel-tab")  ## Setup tab delimter file

for line in reader:                                 ## Read each line in the data frame
    out_line = []                                   ## Setup temp out-line var
    for item in line:

        if item == '':                              ## If item in line is null then put zero
            out_line.append(0)
        elif r"""\t""" in item:                     ## if item in line contains a "\t" character then put count + 1
            out_line.append(item.count(r"""\t""")+1)
        else:                                       ## Else item is 1
            out_line.append(1)
    output_matrix.append(out_line)                  ## Append line into output matrix

for line in output_matrix:
     print line                     ## Print output matrix
```

This code should work... you just have to output the output_matrix to a csv file.

**Output**

```
[1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 3]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Just delete the row and column headers if they exist in your csv file. Otherwise, you can modify my code to incorporate them.

Comment: Straightforward python code! Thanks a lot @budder. I have gained more python knowledge on how to deal with this kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `yourstring.count("\t")` function to get the number of tabs, add 1 to the value to get the number of words. If string is empty, output 0.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Sylver