# How to pull specific data from table, .txt file, Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, extract, helper

I would like to pull data from 2 columns (Input & Surname) from a table that is saved as a .txt file and then generate an output file (by writing a script) with  the two columns (Input and Surname). I know how to do this with normal lines but have no idea where to start with a table format.

Example table -

| Input | Name | Middle-name | Surname | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Sam | Mitchell | Grant | Male |
| 123 | Sameuel | n/a | Fineus | Male |
| 123 | Sharron | Elizabeth | Graceson | Female |

Actual data -

```
Input   Input Type  MGI Gene/Marker ID  Symbol  Name    Feature Type
GO:0003723  Gene Ontology (GO)  MGI:87879   Aco1    aconitase 1 protein coding gene
GO:0003723  Gene Ontology (GO)  MGI:88022   Ang angiogenin, ribonuclease, RNase A family, 5 protein coding gene
GO:0003723  Gene Ontology (GO)  MGI:88042   Apex1   apurinic/apyrimidinic endonuclease 1    protein coding gene
```

The second row of the table starts from GO:0003723 and each new row starts with GO:0003723 as well.

Comment: Please open your .txt input file with a text editor, then copy and paste the contents of the file enclosed by triple backquotes ``` into your question, so that we can see what the file looks like.

Comment: @pythonstudent, is there anything in this question very specific to python 3.8? (as i see, I don't think so). if not, then please change the tag to [tag:python]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the csv module to parse tab seperated value files as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059390/parsing-a-tab-separated-file-in-python).